# Specification and implementation in java class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm having trouble understanding what these terms mean , if someone could explain it to me, i would appreciate it.

I already have 3 classes called :
Shape
Rectangle
Circle

and then I create a class called Triangle

a) what does it mean when they say create a specification of a Triangle ADT similar specification to the Rectangle ADT(above class that I already have )

b) implement the class Triangle

Comment: Are you asking what "specification" and "implementation" mean? Or what an ADT is? (Abstract Data Type, I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Create the specification of a Triangle [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)" means to define what data you would need to define a triangle (three Cartesian coordinates is the most straightforward, but it could be a single point, 3 angles and a side length, or something else).

"Implement the class Triangle" means to write a java class that `implements Shape` but whose internal implementation is the representation in java of your definition from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

ADT: Implementation independent data description that specifies the contents, structure and legal operations on the data.
An ADT has a

```
Name:
Description of the data structure:
Operations:

Construction operations:
Initial values;
Initialization processes;
    For each operation:
    Name of the operation;

Input: External data that comes from the user of this data (client)

Preconditions: Necesssary state of the system before executing this operation;

Process: Actions performed by the data

Output: Data that is output to the client

Post Conditions: State of the system after executing this operation
```

Example:

```
ADT circle
Data: r³ 0 (radius);
Operations

    Costructor:

        Initial values:radius of circle;
        Process: Assign initial value of r;

    Area:

        Input: none;
        Preconditions: none;
        Process: A ¬ p *r*r Output: A
        Postcondition: none

    Circumference:

        Input: None;
        Preconditions: none;
        Process: C ¬ 2*p *r
        Output: C
        Postconditions: none;

End ADT circle;
```